# Can a borderline-autistic adult force themselves to improve?

Tags: autism, neuro-linguistic-prog, cbt

It is agreed that Autism Spectrum disorders / Aspergers etc cannot be 'cured'; they can be managed with coping strategies, and suppressed with medicines, but not solved at the root level.
*[Source: ["autism is not an illness or disease and cannot be cured"]](https://www.autism.org.uk/about/what-is/asd.aspx)*

There are amazing positive changes available to people through Neuro Linguistic Programming or Cognitive Behavioural Therapy (and many others)...
*[Source: [the NHS](https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/cognitive-behavioural-therapy-cbt/), plus do I really have to supply proof that talking - without drugs - can help some people make behavioural changes?!]*
...but I worry that certain autistic traits are so embedded in the brain that large changes would not be accessible to those on the spectrum.

So how do those with autism know **how hard to push themselves** to improve skills that the rest of the population find easier? E.G. Someone might find that endless hours of effort can help them overcome a pedantic obsession of control/detail... but any time spent trying to halt their adherence to routine is a wasted effort.

Is there a way to tell which traits are worth battling, and which are unsolvable?

And what about people on the borderline (self-diagnosed, or appearing very autistic in some areas but not in others). Are their unwanted traits more easily solvable just because they do not have the full set of symptoms?

Comment: Your post contains many questions, and your title does not fit the questions in the body. Please see the help, especially the "don't ask" section that discusses common pitfalls: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I agree with @BryanKrause.  To be a little more specific, you asked about those who are autistic and those who are borderline autistic.  The 2 parts would be better served in separate questions.  Apart from that, it is a good question.

Comment: I think this question has some merit, but it would probably be better to just formulate it as: which autistic traits are more amenable to treatment.

Comment: This question has already received 4 close votes, so I am closing it now.  It still contains a number of issues as noted, such as multiple questions being asked, questions in body not matching title, source not supporting claim made, and having a self-help element.